# Why is method changing the attribute of this Class? (Python)

Tags: python, object, methods, deque

I have a Snake class defined below along with a method Move which is supposed to calculate the new position of the head according to an action , append this element to the blocks array to the snake's block array and then popleft the first element of this list.

```
class Snake:
    actions = [np.array([-1, 0]), np.array([1, 0]), np.array([0, -1]), np.array([0, 1])]

    def __init__(self, start_position, start_direction_idx):
        """

        :type start_position: 2x1 numpy Array
        """
        self.startPosition = None
        self.alive = True
        self.direction = start_direction_idx
        self.length = 1
        self.currentPosition = start_position
        self.blocks = deque([start_position])
        self.blockAtEndofTail = None
```

```
  def move(self, action):
        if self.isMovingBackwards(action):
            action = self.direction

        else:
            self.direction = action
        print('Blocks before anything', self.blocks)
        print('Current position before action',self.currentPosition)

        self.currentPosition += self.actions[self.direction]

        print('Current position after action', self.currentPosition)
        print('Blocks before pop',self.blocks)

        self.blockAtEndofTail = self.blocks.popleft()
        print('Blocks after pop', self.blocks)

        self.blocks.append(self.currentPosition)
        print('Blocks after append', self.blocks)

        print(self.blocks)
```

Here is some sample output below that I get when I run the program .

```
Blocks before anything deque([array([10, 10])])
Current position before action [10 10]
Current position after action [ 9 10]
Blocks before pop deque([array([ 9, 10])])
Blocks after pop deque([])
Blocks after append deque([array([ 9, 10])])
deque([array([ 9, 10])])
```

I got the above but I expected this below:

```
Blocks before anything deque([array([10, 10])])
Current position before action [10 10]
Current position after action [ 9 10]
Blocks before pop deque([array([ 10, 10])])
Blocks after pop deque([])
Blocks after append deque([array([ 9, 10])])
deque([array([ 9, 10])])
```

How is the value in the deque being changed by my method?

Comment: The snake was initialized with start position [10,10] and start_idx=0

Comment: Add the comment to your question, if you feel it's essential to the question.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. As an aside, you probably shouldn't be using NumPy arrays here, at least not in `actions`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips , out of curiosity why shoudnt I use Numpy Arrays here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, objects are references. the value in the `blocks` deque is actually a reference to the same numpy array that `currentPosition` is referencing, since they both were initialized from `start_position`. If you want them to be independent, try copying **the value itself, and not the reference**, using the built-in `copy` function in `Snake.__init__`:

```
self.blocks = deque([start_position.copy()])
```